# How to stop Netbeans from scanning a certain folder

Tags: javascript, php, netbeans, intellisense, netbeans-8

**Situation:**

I have the following file structure for my web project (using php/html/js/css).

```
project-root
|- public
   |- js
   |- img
|- otherFolder
|- nbproject
...
```

- The js-folder holds 4 GiB of javascript libraries and I can't smallen or remove the files.
- We are using NetBeans 8.0.2 on Windows.
- When I open NetBeans it tries to scan all folders (for intelli sense) which takes 4 hours and then bursts the memory.

**Question:**

How can I prevent NetBeans from scanning this folder, but let it who up in the projects tab to browse it.

**Scope:**

- I want no searching capabilities in the js folder.
- I want no autocompletion for the js files.
- I want no auto-detection if something changed on the filesystem for the js folder.
- I just want to browse it manually in the projects bar.

**Trials:**

- adding the js folder to the ignore list -> **no option**, it doens't show up in NB's projects tab at all
- the plugin *ScanOnDemand* -> **no option**, scanning on demand takes 4 hours though and it's not marked as stable, too
- adding the js folder to ignore for code analysis -> **no option**, code analysis is something different from intelli-sense, it scans the whole folder anyway

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I have found to this problem is to not use the projects option and instead just add the project folder to favorites and work with that.

But then you loose the autocomplete features, there is no way to exclude a folder from scans that I know of.